# Image not in the right place[HTML/CSS]

Tags: html, css, position, width

I want that my image(near-logo.png) be in header-content div, which is in header div. Image at the moment is in the left side, but it has to be in the left side of header-content div. 
header div is 100% width, header-content div is 946px width.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Webpage</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div class="header_content">
                <img src="img/near-logo.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#header {
    background-color:#353C3E;
    height:80px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.header-content {
    width:946px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO. Could you rephrase your question? It's hard to understand what you want to do. The Logo is inside of `.header-content` (it's `.header_content` in your css). Do you want it to be centered or do you need it to have some margins to the side? Here is a demo your your current state: http://jsfiddle.net/WuLYE/

Comment: "Image at the moment is in the left side, but it has to be in the left side" 
You can edit your question with the **edit** link bottom left under the question. I think you meant to write, that you want the image to be on the right.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems:

First thing, you have a mistake in your CSS, your class in your div is `<div class="header_content">`but in your CSS it's `.header-content`.

Second thing, delete the `position: absolute` attribute if you want your header content centered.

Answer (score 0):

The image is aligned to the left of the `div` `header_content`. The problem is the `div` class name in your html is `header_content` and the name you have used is `header-content` in your css.

The other thing is you have used `position:absolute` for `header_content`, so that the `margin:0 auto` won't get applied, so remove the `absolute` position. Use the below code

```
.header_content {
    width:946px;
    position:absolute; // Remove this line
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
.header_content {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
}
```